# Data duplication in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, bufferedwriter, cascading

I am trying to write some records that meet certain condition in hadoop from some large files. Operation are being done in Each function in cascading. In unit test output is correct but while trying to do it in hadoop, some of the  lines are being written multiple times. What could be the cause of this. Has anyone gone through this issus.

In each iteration I am backing up the data stored upto previous iteration in temp file and writing backed up data plus new data in required file. This process continues until the last record in done with.

Comment: Provide your sample code.

Comment: There could be chances that the lines being written multiple times are coming from different input files.